# what is meant by new cloud-ready environment-based configuration system in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In ASP.NET core, the use of Web.config file for configuration values and replaced it with JSON or environment variables. How does such configuration is termed as Cloud ready?

> > Cloud-ready configuration
>
> In ASP.NET 5, we eliminated the need to use Web.config file for
>   configuration values. We wanted to make it easier for you to deploy
>   your app to the cloud and have the app automatically read the correct
>   configuration values for that environment. The new system enables you
>   to request named values from a variety of sources (such as JSON, XML,
>   or environment variables). You can decide which formats work best in
>   your situation.
>   http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5

Comment: Go learn Configuration and you'll be cloud-ready: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

ASP Core just re-architected a cloud-ready environment-based configuration system. [Introduction documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/aspnet.html) says

> With ASP.NET Core you gain the following foundational improvements:
>
> - A cloud-ready environment-based [configuration system](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html)

And this configuration system has been:

> ASP.NET Core’s configuration system has been re-architected from previous versions of ASP.NET, which relied on System.Configuration and XML configuration files like web.config. The new [configuration model](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#) provides streamlined access to key/value based settings that can be retrieved from a variety of sources. Applications and frameworks can then access configured settings using the new [Options pattern](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#options-config-objects)